# Everything works, except for buttons. GUI Java

Tags: java, swing, button, layout

Okay I can get text fields and normal text and even images to show but I can not get a button to show. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because I have done the same steps for the rest. Any help would be great thanks!

```
package EventHandling2;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import EventHandling.GUITest;

public class EventMain extends JFrame{

    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventMain gui = new EventMain ();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // when click x close program
        //gui.setSize(600, 300);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("Button Test");
    }

    public void EventMain(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        button = new JButton ("click for text");
        add(button);

        label = new JLabel ("");
        add(label);

        Events e = new Events();
        button.addActionListener(e);
    }

    public class Events implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText("Now you can see words");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()` (just before `setVisible(true)`).  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I have tried doing that and the button still does not show up

Comment: *"I have tried doing that"*  For better help sooner, post an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).**

Comment: @AndrewThompson What's up? It's short, self contained, correct and compilable except the unused `import EventHandling.GUITest;`.

Comment: @johnchen902 *"..correct and compilable except.."*  No, there are no exceptions..  It either is an SSCCE or it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the method:  `void EventMain()`

Constructor has NO return type. Just remove "void". The code will work just fine.

Comment: @LukeWorthing or call `gui.EventMain()`

Answer (score 0):

Your actionListener(e) contains a minor control structure error:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText("Now you can see words");
}
```

Change to:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button) {
           label.setText("Now you can see words");
        }
}
```

Comment: I did that but I still see no button. Thanks for the catch though.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have to remove `void` keyword in `EventMain`'s constructor. Then, creating `JPanel` and add components into it, then add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame.contentPane`.

The following code should work:

```
public class EventMain extends JFrame {

    private final JLabel label;
    private final JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventMain gui = new EventMain();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // when click x
                                                            // close program
        gui.setSize(600, 300);
        gui.setTitle("Button Test");
        gui.setVisible(true);

    }

    public EventMain() {
        // setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        button = new JButton("click for text");
        panel.add(button);

        label = new JLabel("");
        panel.add(label);

        Events e = new Events();
        button.addActionListener(e);

        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    public class Events implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText("Now you can see words");
        }
    }
}
```